# Why did changing from gmail to inbox.com delete contacts from an iPhone4s? Can I retrieve the contacts?

Tags: email, iphone, contacts

I changed my email from gmail to inbox.com on an iPhone4s and discovered most of my contacts are gone. Only recent contacts and Facebook contacts remain. Of course I did not backup the contacts.

Comment: Are the contacts still available if you log into your your Gmail account directly on the web site?

Comment: I will try that and see. The only other solution I can findThanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking here - https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts

If you contacts still exists, you can export them and then import them to where ever you like.

[image]